# HIVE + understanding the hive-metastore logs

Tags: postgresql, hive, apache-spark

we have `HDP` cluster version - `2.6.4` , and we are runs spark streaming app

and we are uses presto cluster in order to run Hive queries

when we look on the `hivemetastore` logs ( under `/var/log/hive` ) , we can see the following warnings , that repeat many times in the log

[image]

```
2020-01-23 16:39:37,182 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.dir does not exist
2020-01-23 16:39:37,182 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.file does not exist
2020-01-23 16:39:37,271 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.dir does not exist
2020-01-23 16:39:37,271 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.file does not exist
2020-01-23 16:42:37,156 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.dir does not exist
2020-01-23 16:42:37,157 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.file does not exist
2020-01-23 16:42:37,239 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.dir does not exist
2020-01-23 16:42:37,239 WARN  [pool-5-thread-200]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3093)) - HiveConf of name hive.log.file does not exist
```

and

```
2020-01-23 16:15:05,827 WARN  [pool-5-thread-110]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:getDatabase(698)) - Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
2020-01-23 16:15:08,252 WARN  [pool-5-thread-110]: metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:executeWithArray(1741)) - Failed to execute [select "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" from "PARTITIONS"  inner join "TBLS" on "PARTITIONS"."TBL_ID" = "TBLS"."TBL_ID"     and "TBLS"."TBL_NAME" = ?   inner join "DBS" on "TBLS"."DB_ID" = "DBS"."DB_ID"      and "DBS"."NAME" = ? inner join "PARTITION_KEY_VALS" "FILTER1" on "FILTER1"."PART_ID" = "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" and "FILTER1"."INTEGER_IDX" = 1 where ((cast("FILTER1"."PART_KEY_VAL" as decimal(21,0)) > ?))] with parameters [profiles_super_spammers, default, 20191223]
```

and

```
2020-01-23 15:44:49,420 WARN  [main]: metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:runTestQuery(265)) - Self-test query [select "DB_ID" from "HIVE".""DBS"] failed; direct SQL is disabled
```

and from log - `hiveserver2.log` we get

```
2020-01-23 15:45:18,180 ERROR [main]: metastore.RetryingHMSHandler (RetryingHMSHandler.java:<init>(81)) - HMSHandler Fatal error: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:6933)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:569)
```

and

```
2020-01-23 15:45:18,180 ERROR [main]: metastore.RetryingHMSHandler (RetryingHMSHandler.java:<init>(81)) - HMSHandler Fatal error: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
```

we are get lost from here because we not sure if all warning in the log are complain about wrong HIVE configuration

I will appreciate to get hint or help about the logs and what is the direction

Comment: What does this have to do with Postgres?